# Inserting checkboxes inside php code

Tags: php, html, mysql, checkbox

I'm trying to use checkboxes to update information in a MySQL database.

The 'Sent' column is a Boolean.

Is there a way to put a checkbox inside my php code,tbody so, instead of    `<td>".$infoItems['Sent']."</td>` there's a checkbox instead of zeroes.

```
<table class="scroll">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Schools Name</th>
      <th>Schools Email</th>
      <th>Sent</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <?php

      $execItems = $conn->query("SELECT Name,SchoolMail,Sent FROM Schools");

      while($infoItems = $execItems->fetch_array())
      {
        echo    "
                <tr>
                    <td>".$infoItems['Name']."</td>
                    <td>".$infoItems['SchoolMail']."</td>

                    <td>".$infoItems['Sent']."</td>
                    /* ^Insert a checkbox here instead of this ^ */
                </tr>
            ";
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: what checkboxes and what update? Didn't you try anything?

Comment: Is this two different questions... ?

Comment: `<input type=checkbox...>` and so on?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this

```
echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$infoItems['Name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$infoItems['SchoolMail'].'</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox"'.($infoItems['Sent']?' checked':'').'
               data-mail="'.$infoItems['SchoolMail'].'"
               data-name="'.$infoItems['Name'].'"
               onchange="ajax_call_function(this)"
               />
    </td>
</tr>' ;
```

It will call a javascript function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_call_function(element) {
        console.log(element.getAttribute("data-name"));
        console.log(element.getAttribute("data-mail"));

        // make your AJAX call to a server-side script 
        // that updates your database with these informations.
        //
        // OR
        //
        // Update some hidden fields in a form and submit it. 

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, but OP also talks about updating information on the database.

Comment: Thanks for the input! That helped with the checkboxes, but how do I make it so when I insert the SchoolMail and send the email, the checkbox gets updated?

Comment: Tip: Instead of fighting the quotes, either omit them, as you can for most HTML tag attributes with single word values, or use the other kind. For example: `<input type=checkbox>` or `<input type='checkbox'>` both work.

Comment: @Felmorne I've updated my anwser... But there are so many way to do this.

Comment: @Syscall Sorry if I'm being intrusive but is there a way that we can communicate directly, if you're available of course

Comment: @Felmorne I'm really sorry but I can't right now (I've to go). If you want a more precise anwser, I think you have to post more informations of what you want, some code about your server-side and database.

Comment: @Syscall Thanks for the reply, I'll keep that in mind next time I post